# Integrate paypal with ionic PayPalMobile is not defined

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to integrate paypal with ionic but I'm having problems.

I'm using [PayPal-Cordova-Plugin](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin)

In the documentation says: add

```
<script type = "text / javascript" src = "js / paypal-mobile-js-helper.js"> </ script>
```

in **index.html**

I do not have this folder / js with this file, but I searched and when giving ionic run android this folder will be created

But when giving ionic run android I get this message on my console:

```
file:///android_asset/www/js/paypal-mobile-js-helper.js 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

And when I try to use some library function I get: PayPalMobile is not defined

I'm using this factory: https://gist.github.com/mssdineshsambial/f679ab69597c49b25f25

**EDIT:**

So I removed the platform, removed the plugin and am adding the plugin again

But I'm 10 minutes into this process.
[image]

Thanks